# Collagen, are fibrils arranged in overlapping fashion too just like tropocollagen?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, extra-cellular-matrix

Collagen molecules (tropocollagen) are interlinked into fibrils, with a banded structure showing the spaces ("lacunae") between the molecules. Do fibrils in turn also interlink in a similar way, or, do fibrils run from end to end in the fibers?